# Update query with Join in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to do the following:

```
UPDATE a
SET col1 = B.col1,
col3= B.col4
FROM table A 
JOIN table B on a.col2=b.col2
WHERE A.col5 = B.col5;
```

However, this throws me the following error:

**Error while compiling statement: FAILED-ParseException- Missing EOF at 'from' near 'col4'**

I tried rearranging the set and from clause, but wasnt able to execute the query. ParseExceptions kept cropping up again and again.
My table types, coloumn datatypes are all same. Running static updates on the table work perfectly fine.

Is there any way that I can run an update with join in hive? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hive doesn't support that. You can use only the following structure:

```
UPDATE a SET col1 =..., col3=... WHERE ...
```

However you have 2 options to update table:

1. subquery

   ```
   UPDATE a SET col1 =..., col3=... WHERE col2 in (SELECT ...)
   ```

   It's not your case
2. insert overwrite

   ```
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE a SELECT B.col1, col2, A.col3, ...
   ```

   Be careful! It overwrites old table and you can lose or corrupt data if query is wrong. Test twice before executing on real data.

Comment: One more thing, can you please explain how insert overwrite can replace update? Doesnt Update change the value of a coloumn while insert adds a row into the table?

Comment: INSERT OVERWRITE replaces content of the chosen table or partition with the output of corresponding select statement. In select statement you can use joins and mix variables from multiple tables. So your goal is to write 'select' with output you want to see after update.

Answer (score 2):

Since Hive 2.2, Hive supports Hive ACID Merge that allow doing this type of update.

For example:

```
MERGE INTO a
USING b
ON a.col2=b.col2
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET col1=b.col1, col3=b.col4;
```

[reference](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/using-hiveql/content/hive_merge_data_in_hive_tables.html)